# Is it possible to keep track of record of user interaction from background in android?

Tags: android

I am working on an android application which can be used to capture the sequence of user interaction on android device. Starting from when the device is powered ON.

This is to be done by an application, based on the users event a script (Comma (`,`) delimited text format) will be generated which can be used further to played back the records of events.The application must have various button to start, pause, stop button for recording, script creation should also work according to button pressed.

Is it possible to keep track of record of user interaction from background in android?

I didn't get anything about this. Any help or suggestion is well appreciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The application you are describing is a KeyLogger. Unless you have root permissions you cannot do this.  If you could it would represent a huge security gap in android. It would allow any app to capture credit card numbers, passwords, email address, etc...

Your only options are to use root privileges or write a custom android keyboard; however, that will only let you record keystrokes when your custom keyboard is used.

A better question is what are you trying to do, as there is probably a better way to acheive what you want.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Actualy i am working on application which can be used in automation testing. Suppose if any one want to test any application and perform various steps like button click, input text value etc... i want to keep record of these events (in the form of script), which can be used later to perform all these step again and again. automatically.